# How to check whether a pixel inside a CCSprite is transparent or not

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

Every CCSprite is a regtangle area, but some of the parts of it, is visible ,means image that we see and other part are not. So i want to know when i touch on CCsprite whether the touch point is visible area or transparent area, Any way to check this, like getting the pixel color of the touch point??

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to do this with OpenGL API, but it would be wrong solution. I propose to detect tap point inside sprite shape (that would be manually defined). To calculate bounding shape you may use for example this tool: [SpriteHelper](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spritehelper/id416068717?mt=12&ls=1). To check point inside polygon (even non-convex) there is good algorythm: [Determining if a point lies on the interior of a polygon](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/polygonmesh/). I use this method in my iPhone game.

As for efficienty of this method compared to direct checking of pixel opacity:

- performance: to get pixel in OpenGL you need to lock texture and read data from it, this will drop FPS
- accuracy: tap is not a mouse click, it means some region, so you would probably check some area (for example circle of tap) inside sprite shape
- flexibility: you may tune your shape as you want

PS: If you definitely want to check pixels, a good solution will be to make additional boolean map of texture pixels (where each bit responds to pixel treshold).

Comment: may I get more information on this ..that would be great .. ALso that alogrithm link is broken

Comment: I updated the link to algorithm. There is detailed description with source code.